# QP and QR are two tangent lines to three symmetrically aligning circles. Find angle $\angle$PQR

Tags: geometry

The distance from the center of the small circle to the largest is given as 16 times the radius of the small circle. Find the angle PQR.

That is the only information given. I have worked out using symmetry of shapes and the fact that tangents are equal in length. The answer is given as 60 degrees.

Could we assume we have an equilateral triangle here? If yes, how is it formed.

[image: circles and tangents]

Comment: Missing figure please.

Comment: We need to find the angle PQR such that what? What are we trying to solve so that the answer is 60 degrees? This information is needed to be able to produce the picture.

Comment: Maybe see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631687/578053

Comment: To be clear: Do you mean that "the distance from the center of the smallest circle to **the center of** the largest is given as ..."?

Comment: You cannot *assume* there is an equilateral triangle in the figure, but you may *deduce* it. ... Let the smallest radius be $r$, and let the middle radius be $mr$; then, what's the largest radius? If you can express $16r$ in terms of those three radii, you can find the scale factor $m$. From here, a simple geometric argument will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the radii of the small, middle and large circles, respectively. Note that there are three similar triangles with the three radius lines as one of their respective sides. Then, establish the ratios below,

$$\frac{a}{x}=\frac{b}{x+a+b}= \frac{c}{x+a+2b+c}$$

where $x$ is the distance from Q to the center of the small circle. The above ratios lead to,

$$b^2=ac$$

Then, substitute the given $c+2b+a=16a$ to get,

$$15a^2-2ab-b^2 = 0$$

which yields $\frac ab =\frac13$. From the diagram, we have 
$$\sin \frac{\angle PQR}{2} = \frac{b-a}{b+a} = \frac{1-\frac ab}{1+\frac ab} = \frac12 $$

Thus,

$$\angle PQR = 60^\circ$$

Comment: Ok. so right, I also succeeded after following Blue's guidance. I then assumed a geometric sequence for big radius as R = the product of square of m and r. Is this always true?

Comment: @WaitaraMburu - R=mr happens to be true. However, it is not a given; it needs to be derived as part of the solution.

Comment: @WaitaraMburu: It's certainly true that, if $r$ is the small radius, you can write the middle radius as $mr$ for some $m$. That the big radius is then $m$-times the middle radius (and therefore equal to $m^2r$) follows from a straightforward proportionality argument.